# Biztalk SFTP Configuration Optimization

Tags: ftp, sftp, biztalk, biztalk-2016

We are using Biztalk 2016 and biztalk has a 1000+ receive locations with SFTP adapter. We need to connection pooling and thats why we set our Connection Limit to 5 but sometimes SFTP adapter does not read our file in SFTP.

Whats is the optimized configuration for SFTP adapter in this scenario. We have a time critic works which are triggered with SFTP file and if SFTP does not work our works fails.

While using FTP adapter, there is no problem with triggering a file in interval but for 1000+ receive location, opening too many connection and this caused a network problems.

What is your advise for this issue?

Current configuration:

[image: Current configuration]

Comment: Hi Ibrahimsen.  Did my answer below help you in resolving the issue?

Comment: Hi Dijkgraff, Nope, we already set adapter and host options as below suggesions before. Our problem is pooling interval. We have an 1000+ receive locations with same host but SFTP adapter stop listening after a while.

Comment: Then I would suggest you set up another host and host instance and split the receive locations across the two.  The other work around I've seen used is to schedule a restart of the host instance on a regular basis.

Answer (score 1):

As per a blog article I wrote [Max worker threads for SFTP, MQSC or DB in BizTalk](https://cdijkgraaf.wordpress.com/2020/06/25/max-worker-threads-for-sftp-mqsc-or-db-in-biztalk/)

Recommendations for SFTP Receive Locations

1. Have a dedicated host for receive locations using SFTP
2. Increase the Maximum Worker threads setting to 500 on that host instance
3. Check how frequently you poll (the default is 5 seconds), increase the delay if that is not needed.
4. Put a schedule on to only poll during the periods you need.
5. Disable message body tracking if it is not needed.